# Setup Python program as systemd service

Tags: 18.04, python, services, systemd

I've made a program to log certain system stats, and I would like to run that program as a Linux service so I can easily manage it (start, stop, etc). I've spent hours researching and trying things, but I can't seem to get my systemd service file configured correctly.

So far I have this in my service file: (clopper is my username, resourciter is my python program name)

```
[Unit]
Description=Simplified Resourciter logger service
After=syslog.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=clopper
Group=clopper
WorkingDirectory=/home/clopper/resourciter/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/clopper/resourciter/runMonitor.py
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But I keep having this error when I try to start the service:

```
pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [clopper]
```

I can't seem to find a definitive reference about the ins and outs of configuring a systemd service file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your Python script is trying to use `sudo` to execute commands as root.

That won't really work out of the box when running your script as a service, since there's no terminal attached to the script, so `sudo` will not have a way to ask for a password to allow your script to run the command as root.

There are ways to configure sudo to run commands without prompting for a password and without requiring a terminal to be attached... But before we go that route, would you consider running your whole script as root instead and not using `sudo` inside it? That would simplify things...

Comment: So my program 'runMonitor.py' actually sudo runs my real logger program every 30 seconds (and logs any errors, etc to a log file). So yeah, if I could get around the sudo command by running the script as root, that would work I think.
How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Just remove the `User=clopper` and `Group=clopper`, in which case systemd will run it as root. You might want to remove the calls to `sudo` from your script, since they're not needed if you're running as root (though it's possible everything will keep working even with `sudo` if you already run as root.)

Comment: That fixed that problem (even leaving the sudo commands in the code).

Comment: However now my python program is crashing because it can't find a package import. Any idea why it's having this issue?

Comment: Possibly because you have the modules installed for your user only, not root... Try to import the module on an interactive Python session and look at `sys.modules` to see where it's coming from. You can try to set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable for it to be able to find it as root...

Comment: You might also want to look into systemd timer units to schedule running your script every 30s, in which case you might not need an additional script, just the one you're currently running as root every 30s already...

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you so much!
Also concerning the systemd timers; I was considering using those, but I wanted to make my own script to run the logger program so that I could handle any possible errors, and possibly do things like sending a notification to other devices warning me about the error.

Comment: That's great @Jyclop! If you want to look into using systemd timers for this (even if you still want a Python wrapper), post a separate question with more details of what your Python script is currently doing, we'll help you look at an alternative setup using systemd timers instead. Cheers!